# How to use a list comprehension to store the nested list of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I was wondering, if I had `nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` how would I be able to break the loop and only storing the items in each of the nested lists, what I mean by loop is that when I try:

```
result = [[value_1 for value_1 in a_list] for a_list in nested_list]
```

The only thing result will have is...well the exact list we started with :/. So what would be a way of storing the items like this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` using a list comprehension on `nested_list`. I repeat, a list comprehension, not a 'for loop'.

Comment: Why you don't want to use for loop?

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thank you for that! I will research on it right away

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL I just wanted to see if there was a way to use a list comprehension on it

Comment: `result = [x for a_list in nested_list for x in a_list]`.

Comment: @CodingGrind ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output = [item for sublist in nested_list for item in sublist]
print(output) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Explanation**:

When you use list comprehension for nested loops, the structure of the expression is as follows:

- The leftmost expression, `item`, is what will contain the returned list.
- The first loop from left is the most outer loop, `for sublist in nested_list` so first you iterate over the each element in your input list and name it `sublist`.
- The right most loop, `for item in sublist` is the most inner loop. In your case this loops iterates over each element of the `sublist` and name it `item` which will eventually will be returned in the output.

Comment: Hi thank you for that answer, it worked! I'm not sure about something though, why do that work and the more logical approach doesn't: `[item for item in sublist for sublist in nested_list]` where can I learn more about it as well (syntax).

Comment: @CodingGrind: The loops read from left to right, with the leftmost loop being the "outer" loop, and the rightmost the most "inner" loop. Your proposed approach doesn't work because `sublist` doesn't exist until the "outer" loop has looped once. Read [the functional programming howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) for more.

Comment: @CodingGrind I've added an explanation, does it make sense for you?

Comment: @ShadowRanger tell me if I understood incorrectly, but in list comprehensions python reads the any for loops that it contains, and then it checks if and else and what to store for it?

Comment: @CodingGrind: There is no `else` in list comprehension syntax (if you see one, it's part of a ternary conditional expression embedded in the listcomp, but it's not part of listcomp special behaviors). As for checking `if`s, that's ordered the same way as the `for`s (so `if` that are further left are checked less frequently, and control the inner loops).